# Retrieving two values from each line of a text document

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the contents from a file, the ping result and the description. The everything through pinging works, but I how do I get the description in my output?

```
GC D:\Temp\System.txt | %{
    If (Test-Connection $_ -Quiet -Count 2){
        Write-Host "$_ is UP" -b Green
    }
    Else{
        Write-Host "$_ is Down" -b Red
    }
}
PAUSE
```

Content with IP addresses to ping and their descriptions

```
10.200.11.2     Firewall
10.200.11.14    Test1
192.168.254.81  Test2
192.168.254.133 Test3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions, `($_ -replace "\s.+","")` - All that up to the space (tabulation)
`($_ -replace ".+\s","")` - All that after a space (tabulation)

```
  GC D:\Temp\System.txt | %{
If (Test-Connection ($_ -replace "\s.+","") -Quiet -Count 2){
    Write-Host "$_ is UP" -b Green
    Write-Host ($_ -replace ".+\s","")
}
Else{
    Write-Host "$_ is Down" -b Red
    Write-Host ($_ -replace ".+\s","")
}
```

String `Write-Host ($_ -replace ".+\s","")` are descriptions

Answer (score 0):

To add several other ways to do this:

Since it looks like you are using tabs delimiters you could split on the tabs.

```
GC D:\Temp\System.txt | % {
    $hostname = ($_.Split("`t") | ? {$_ -ne ""})[0]
    $description = ($_.Split("`t") | ? {$_ -ne ""})[1]
    If (Test-Connection $hostname -Quiet -Count 2) {
        Write-Host "Hostname: $hostname Description: $description is UP" -b Green
    } Else {
        Write-Host "Hostname: $hostname Description: $description is Down" -b Red
    }
}
```

Or you could import it as a CSV with a tab delimiter

```
Import-CSV D:\Temp\System.txt -Delimiter `t -Header hostname,description | % {
    If (Test-Connection $_.hostname -Quiet -Count 2) {
        Write-Host "Hostname: $($_.hostname) Description: $($_.description) is UP" -b Green
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Hostname = $_.hostname
            Description = $_.description
            Status = "Up"
        }
    } Else {
        Write-Host "Hostname: $($_.hostname) Description: $($_.description) is Down" -b Red
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Hostname = $_.hostname
            Description = $_.description
            Status = "Down"
        }
    }
} | ConvertTo-HTML | Out-File D:\Temp\Example.html
```

Comment: Thanks brothers, works perfect!! Is it possible to get the output in an html page?

Comment: @Rachid Answer updated with Html output. Also if an answer worked for you it is best practice to accept it.

Comment: thx a lot! But the conversion to html doesn't work! What is the meaning of Out-file? Should i make this file in the directory?

Comment: `Out-File` creates a text file with the output that it receives. That command should save a file `Example.html` in `D:\Temp\`. If you remove the `| Out-File ..` you should see what is being saved.

Comment: the output format header should be on the top of the column, but i get this output:Format-Table Hostname: 10.200.11.2      Description: Host station is UP
Format-Table Hostname: 10.200.11.14     Description: Router(Gateway) is UP
Format-Table Hostname: 192.168.254.81   Description: Test2 is UP
Format-Table Hostname: 192.168.254.133  Description: Test3 is UP
Format-Table Hostname: 10.193.007.161   Description: Ruppeltunnel is UP
Press Enter to continue...: